# R test if a file exists, and is not a directory

Tags: r, file, directory

I have an R script that takes a file as input, and I want a general way to know whether the input is a file that exists, and is not a directory.

In Python you would do it this way: [How do I check whether a file exists using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python), but I was struggling to find anything similar in R.

What I'd like is something like below, assuming that the `file.txt` actually exists:

```
input.good = "~/directory/file.txt"
input.bad = "~/directory/"

is.file(input.good) # should return TRUE
is.file(input.bad) #should return FALSE
```

R has something called file.exists(), but this doesn't distinguish files from directories.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a `dir.exists` function in all recent versions of R.

```
file.exists(f) && !dir.exists(f)
```

Answer (score 25):

The solution is to use [file_test()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/filetest.html)

This gives shell-style file tests, and can distinguish files from folders.

E.g.

```
input.good = "~/directory/file.txt"
input.bad = "~/directory/"

file_test("-f", input.good) # returns TRUE
file_test("-f", input.bad) #returns FALSE
```

From the manual:

> **Usage**
>
> file_test(op, x, y) Arguments
>
> **op**     a character string specifying the test to be performed. Unary
>   tests (only x is used) are "-f" (existence and not being a directory),
>   "-d" (existence and directory) and "-x" (executable as a file or
>   searchable as a directory). Binary tests are "-nt" (strictly newer
>   than, using the modification dates) and "-ot" (strictly older than):
>   in both cases the test is false unless both files exist.
>
> **x**, **y**   character vectors giving file paths.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `is_file(path)` from the `fs` package.