# File copy, making directories as necessary

Tags: r

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10268255/, I would like a function that automatically makes sub-directories where they don't exist, when `file.copy` is used. Current I am getting the error:

```
In file.copy( ... :
  'recursive' will be ignored as 'to' is not a single existing directory
```

Unfortunately using a function like:

```
my.file.copy<- function(from, to, ...) {
    todir <- dirname(to)
    if (!isTRUE(file.info(todir)$isdir)) dir.create(todir, recursive=TRUE)
    file.copy(from = from,  to = to, ...)
}
```

does not work as `dirname` strips the last subdirectory if `to` is a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you are going to pass `to` parameter to the function, we can use one of these.

1) If you are going to pass `to` with only directory name and expect it to take filename from `from` argument, we can use the below function

```
my.file.copy_dir <- function(from, to, ...) {
   if (!dir.exists(to))  dir.create(to, recursive = TRUE) 
   file.copy(from = from,  to = paste0(to, basename(from)), ...)
}
```

2) If you are going to pass `to` as complete path to new file name we can use

```
my.file.copy_file <- function(from, to, ...) {
   if (!dir.exists(dirname(to)))  dir.create(dirname(to), recursive = TRUE) 
   file.copy(from = from,  to = to, ...)
}
```

and use them as :

```
my.file.copy_dir("/path/of/file/report.pdf", "/new/path/of/file/")
```

and

```
my.file.copy_file("/path/of/file/report.pdf", "/new/path/of/file/abc.pdf")
```

Comment: is there a way for the function to determine whether it is a directory or file being passed automatically?

Comment: ah I suppose I could use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147901/r-test-if-a-file-exists-and-is-not-a-directory

thanks

Comment: @Alex yes you can use that but ideally it is better to standardize the inputs. If you look at `file.copy` it accepts complete path **only** and not folder and path both.

Comment: I don't see that "file.copy it accepts complete path only..."